# Run custom plugin as part of the maven release but before the version is updated to the next snapshot

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have written a Maven plugin which will call a web service with details about my project including the version number.  I only want to run this when my project is released, not on the deployment of snapshots.

I have a Jenkins job that manages the `build/deploy/release` process.  If I modify the Release Goals and Options from

`-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform --debug`  to

```
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform my-plugin:dostuff --debug
```

Will that achieve what I want?  Or will the release:perform to the build and deployment of my release version and then update the POM to the next snapshot version before my plugin runs?

If so is there a way to achieve what I want which is, on running the Jenkins job to perform the release of 1.0, have the release plugin update the POM to 1.0, build it and deploy it then run my plugin to call the web service before having the release plugin update the version to 1.1-SNAPSHOT.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add your plugin to the POM, configuring it to run in an appropriate phase of the standard lifecycle. Additionally, you can program your plugin to only perform the action when a release is happening, i.e. by checking whether the version of the project ends with `-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Where should I get the version from?  Just tried adding my plugin after the release:perform and go the SNAPSHOT version at the start of the process by using the MavenProject object taken as a parameter i.e. @Parameter(defaultValue = "${project}", required = true, readonly = true)
    MavenProject project; within my Mojo class extending AbstractMojo.

Comment: Inside the plugin, you can read the version from the `MavenProject` object. Make sure you do not add your goal to the command line (in Jenkins), but to the POM.

Comment: I got this working.  After I added the plugin to the POM with the phase set to goal the, project version set in the `MavenProject` object got me the release version rather than a snapshot on a release build.  Thanks for your assistance.